# ¿como puedo mantener la sesion en otra pagina ASPX y VB?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Tengo la pagina login y obviamente ya valida el usuario y contraseña de una base de datos en SQL, lo que quiero es que en otra pagina me muestre el nombre de usuario (es una masterpage), de la persona que se logeo.

Comment: Aunque no da suficiente informacion, como si las paginas estan en el mismo dominio o es .net con VB Clásico. Por mi experiencia te puedo aconsejar utilizar JWT (JSON Web Token) que son básicamente archivos JSON que contienen una llave cifrada que el cliente te envía en cada request para validarse. Eso te permite cambiar de sitios en distintos dominios sin tener que hacer complicados pasos entre los servidores.
Para mas información te sugiero https://jwt.io/ que es completamneten gratis. Nose si open source.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa `Sesion("invariable") = nombre usuario`

Y para recuperarla `Sesion("invariable").ToString()`

Comment: Gracias me sirvió de mucho